# ValidationMessageFor display outside the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this validation message for a field in MVC view outside the begin form. However it is not displaying that.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
```

Is there any possible way I can achieve this? Since I don't wanna use a Jquery or Javascript function just to validate this.

Comment: Can you post your view code. Also why do you want it to be outside the form element.

Comment: Hi I want it because there are multiple forms inside a view. Hence all the errors should be shown above.

Comment: That multiple forms, Are the data sent by ´Ajax.BeginForm´?

Comment: No it is HTML.Beginform ex : `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddressUpdate", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "AddressInfoUpdate" }))`

Comment: But, Where you check if the value of `OldPassword` is wrong? in the browser or in server code, and are you check values in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidationMessageFor` only works if the fields / Controls are inside the form post action for that controller. Otherwise need to do separate methods like `JavaScript / Ajax / ViewBag` to get the error.

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep the validation message inside the form with a Div tag.
2. Make the Div display none.
3. On button click, check the IsValid property of the form
4. If in valid, then copy the HTML() of the Div and put it into another div which will be outside the form.

Its not a clean solution, but the trick will work

Answer (score 0):

It only works if `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property)` is inside the form. However, I managed to find a workaround that also updates the outside div when there are element changes, i.e., when the error messages change without re-submitting the form:

1. Place a `<div id="outside-form"></div>` outside your form.
2. Place a `<div id="inside-form" style="display:none;"></div>` inside your form, which contains all `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property)` statements.
3. This is the nasty part, in your jquery.validate.js, find the following:

`form: function() {.....}` and just before the function return add `$("#outside-form").html($("#inside-form").html());`. This ensures that your outside-div will be updated every time the whole form is validated.

`element: function( element ) {.....}` and just before the function return add `$("#outside-form").html($("#inside-form").html());`. This ensures that your outside-div will be updated every time each form element is validated.

That's it! I was wondering if there's some way of extending the `form` and `element` objects without changing the .js file itself.. do you have any clue about this?